# Inserting a user sign-up record using mysqli

Tags: beginner, php, mysqli

**My Code:
Connectivity(php)**

```
<?php

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","webchat_data");
//if($conn)
//{
//  echo "hi";
//}
if(!$conn){
    die("CONNECTION FAILED" .mysqli_connect_error());
}



?>
```

**Signup**

```
<?php
include 'connectivity.php';
$uname=($_POST['uname']);
$email=($_POST['Email']);
$pass=($_POST['Password']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO `sign-up`(USERNAME,EMAIL_ID,PASSWORD) VALUES('$uname','$email','$pass')";
//$result=$conn->query($sql);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

header("Location:index.php");





?>
```

Someone told me that my query is good for a learner, but not for real world applications. Please make some recommendations to make this code more suitable for real world scenarios.

Comment: Two words: [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Based on the size of the code this isn't really a question for code review, but there are 28 answers to this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php. As @Glorfindel indicated this is wide open for a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: There's so many bad practices at play here that I don't even know where to start. You may want to learn more about PHP before working with real user data. Start with the [most common PHP questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?tab=Frequent) at [so].

Comment: I would NOT like to register an account with the site that is using the posted code.

Answer (score 2):

Like it was said in the comments, this code needs not a review but just some basic practices. That said, good basic practices are a rare specimen in the wild, so you cannot be blamed, given the number of awful tutorials out there. Luckily I am the renowned collector of good practices and here you are

## Connectivity

There ate many things that could be improved in your connectivity file. To name a few

- the connection character set must be configured to avoid issues with characters
- the proper error reporting mode for mysqli must be set
- the connection error smust be not bluntly echoed out

All these issues are covered in my article [How to connect properly using mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect): so let's take the code from there:

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'webchat_data';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    $conn->set_charset($charset);
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
```

## Password hashing

In two words, never store passwords in plain text. Use password_hash() function instead. This topic is thoroughly explained in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely

## Prepared statements

Just never add a variable to SQL query directly, but mark its place with a question mark instead. Then bind the actual variable and finally call execute()

In detail this matter is explained in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

So here is your signup code reviewed

```
<?php
include 'connectivity.php';

$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$pass  = password_hash($_POST['Password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `sign-up`(USERNAME,EMAIL_ID,PASSWORD) VALUES(?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $uname,$email,$pass);
$stmt->execute();

header("Location:index.php");
```

Answer (score -1):

The most important points:

Never use User-Input in unsecured queries. Use prepared statements!

Never save passwords in cleartext. A common form is hashing.

Unfortunately, these topics would exceed this format.